# DataGridView filtering using a TextBox (C#) without a DataTable

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview, filter, filtering

I am using a SQlite database for this project and I want to filter some data in a `DataGridView` by a `TextBox`.

I read other posts on StackOverflow, but they don't solve my problem.

The function that loads the data to `DataGridView`:

```
private void loadDataToDataGrideView()
{
    using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(stringConnection))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            stringSql = @"SELECT * FROM `tbl_user`;";
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stringSql,  connection);
            SQLiteDataReader readData = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (readData.Read())
            {
                dataG_Customer.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                readData.GetValue(readData.GetOrdinal("user_name")),
                readData.GetValue(readData.GetOrdinal("user_family")),
                readData.GetValue(readData.GetOrdinal("user_id_card")),
                readData.GetValue(readData.GetOrdinal("user_mobile")),
                readData.GetValue(readData.GetOrdinal("user_phone")),
                readData.GetValue(readData.GetOrdinal("user_regiter_date")),                                     readData.GetValue(readData.GetOrdinal("user_address")),
                readData.GetValue(readData.GetOrdinal("id")),
                readData.GetValue(readData.GetOrdinal("user_status"))
                });
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
            catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

In the textbox I use this code:

```
private void txt_search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = dataG_Customer.DataSource;
    bs.Filter = "name" + " like '%" + txt_search.Text + "%'";
    dataG_Customer.DataSource = bs;
}
```

Comment: Not clear why you don't want to use a DataTable but at this point I would create a class with the properties matching your fields, then set these properties while looping, adding each class instance to a list of this class and finally set the datasource of the gridview. At this point the code in the textchanged event could be made working on the list

Comment: Thanks Steve for comment. i write this code and did not want to change the code :-) okey I try DataTable ;-)